# Optimizing an algorithm for combining lists of variable sizes

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I created an algorithm that combines data from various lists into a single one. This question is about designing an efficient/optimized version of this algorithm.

**Background:**

The inputs comprise lists of tuples containing (value, submission-time) pairs. These can be thought of as 2D arrays. Here are example inputs:

```
l1 = [(value-11, time-11),(value-12, time-12),(value-13, time-13),(value-14, time-14),(value-15, time-15)]
l2 = [(value-21, time-21),(value-22, time-22)]
l3 = [(value-31, time-31),(value-32, time-32),(value-33, time-33),(value-34, time-34)]
l4 = [(value-41, time-41),(value-42, time-42),(value-43, time-43),(value-44, time-44),(value-45, time-45)]
l5 = [(value-51, time-51)]
.
.
.
ln = [(value-n1, time-n1),(value-n2, time-n2),....(value-nm, time-nm)]
```

Note that:

- The lists are of a variable size.
- The lists are `sorted` by time of submission.
- The most-recent tuple is appearing in the left-most position.
- The time in each tuple is the actual time of submission of said tuple into the list.
- These lists were not filled one after another. I.e. `time-21` is not necessarily later than `time-15`.

**The requirement:**

I am trying to produce a combined list from the given inputs. The result is to contain the most recent `k` tuples, taken from all input lists. Let us set `k=20` for now.

**Current approach:**

I retrieve up to 20 elements from *every* list. I combine them into a singular list, sorted by submission-time of each tuple. Then I just select the first 20 elements from this result.

Needless to say, that is quite a brute-force method of doing this. It does not scale well as the number of lists scales. I was assuming I can do better than that, but have not been able to come up with anything so far. It will be great to get an illustrative example from an expert on how to do this kind of operation as efficiently as possible.

In case it matters, my personal preference is python.

---

*p.s. there is one hack we can employ to side-step the problem. And that is to maintain a combined global list all along. Let us ignore that for the purposes of this question.*

Comment: My approach would be to sort the list of lists, and then maintain that sorting as I pop `k` elements off the topmost list.  You wouldn't want to call `sort` on each pop because you know that most of the list is already sorted; you just need to bubble the topmost list to its correct position before doing the next pop.

Comment: If the process is online, maintain an independent heap with k or less elements. If the process is offline, merge k elements from the m lists in O(k m log m).

Comment: For realistic advice/benchmarks we need realistic data. How many lists do you have in reality, how long are they, and how large is your real k? Ideally you'd provide actual data or code that generates realistic data.

Comment: @superbrain currently I have ~30 lists, ~1000 objs each (updated and trimmed almost every few seconds), and `k=20`. So that is the real scenario I am dealing with. These are actually feeds of a social app. And what we are attempting to achieve is a `Fan-out-on-load` for every user who logs in to view their compiled feed (around 100K daily actives). It is in contrast to a `Fan-out-on-write` - I ruled that out in the `p.s.` statement at the end of my question, due to reasons outside the bounds of the question. Would be nice to get guidance from you.

Comment: @גלעדברקן it is indeed an online process. Could you elaborate your answer with an illustrative example

Comment: @HassanBaig what I meant by "online" is that an addition of any single element to any of the lists is available to examine. In that case, if we have a min heap that stores at most k items, the algorithm is: if there's less than k items in the heap, push the element; otherwise, if the element is more recent than the min (i.e., has a greater timestamp), pop the heap and push the new element so we maintain a count of k latest (i.e., with the greatest timestamps).

Comment: @גלעדברקן  oh I see. I have already addressed that in the `p.s.` portion of the question. I think that is what you are referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an efficient way to do it, using [heapq.merge](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) that allows you to merge sorted lists lazily.

(Edit: I just realized that I had misread a part of the question - the most recent items, so the ones with the greater time, are on the left, at the start of the list, not at the end as I had supposed. So, same thing, but we don't even have to iterate the lists in reversed order):

```
from heapq import merge
from itertools import islice
from operator import itemgetter

l1 = [("a1", 40),("b1", 30),("c1", 20),("d1", 10)]
l2 = [("a2", 32),("b2", 24),("c2", 9)]
l3 = [("a3", 35),("b3", 18),("c3", 16)]

data = [l1, l2, l3]

out = list(islice(merge(*data, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True), 5))

print(out)
# [('a1', 40), ('a3', 35), ('a2', 32), ('b1', 30), ('b2', 24)]
```

We give our lists to `merge`, that will iterate on them lazily, taking each time the tuple that has the larger `time`.

The  time is the value at index 1 in each tuple, hence `key=itemgetter(1)`.

The default behavior of `merge` is to take the item with the smallest value, so we have to use `reverse=True` to tell it to choose the largest.

We then use `islice` to get the first (here 5) items out of this, and we convert it to a list.

So, as everything is based on iterators, only the necessary items are retrieved from the lists.

---

In case the tuples would have been sorted in the opposite order, as I had first imagined, with the latest at the end of the lists: we would have to iterate on the lists in reverse order:

```
from heapq import merge
from itertools import islice
from operator import itemgetter

l1 = [("a1", 10),("b1", 20),("c1", 30),("d1", 40)]
l2 = [("a2", 9),("b2", 24),("c2", 32)]
l3 = [("a3", 16),("b3", 18),("c3", 35)]

data = [l1, l2, l3]

out = list(islice(merge(*map(reversed, data), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True), 5))

print(out)
# [('d1', 40), ('c3', 35), ('c2', 32), ('c1', 30), ('b2', 24)]
```

---

To answer your last comment, here is a solution working for Python versions older than 3.5, before the `key` and `reverse` keyword arguments to `heapq.merge` were introduced.

The idea is still to work with iterators and generator expressions, so that pieces of data are accessed and treated one at a time. The key is not a big problem, but replacing `reverse` is a bit more complicated, as `merge` expects the lists it receives to be sorted in increasing order.

A solution is to decorate each tuple read from the list by adding a first field that will be in opposite order of the time. As we can't use "negative time", we can use the timedelta `datetime.max - time`.
We'll just have to remove this first field before returning the tuple.

I created a generator that iterates on a list and yields the decorated tuples. I separated the generator expression to avoid a long, hard to read line:

```
# Before Python 3.5, merge doesn't support key and reverse

from heapq import merge
from itertools import islice
from datetime import datetime

def decorated_with_reverse_datetime(lst):
    for value, time in lst:
        yield (datetime.max - time, value, time)


l1 = [("a1", datetime(2020, 12, 13, 12, 40)),
      ("b1", datetime(2020, 12, 13, 12, 30)),
      ("c1", datetime(2020, 12, 13, 12, 20)),
      ("d1", datetime(2020, 12, 13, 12, 10))]

l2 = [("a2", datetime(2020, 12, 13, 12, 32)),
      ("b2", datetime(2020, 12, 13, 12, 24)),
      ("c2", datetime(2020, 12, 13, 12, 9))]

l3 = [("a3", datetime(2020, 12, 13, 12, 35)),
      ("b3", datetime(2020, 12, 13, 12, 18)),
      ("c3", datetime(2020, 12, 13, 12, 16))]

data = [l1, l2, l3]

sorted_tuples = merge(*map(decorated_with_reverse_datetime, data))
undecorated = (tup[1:] for tup in sorted_tuples)
out = list(islice(undecorated, 5))

print(out)
[('a1', datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 13, 12, 40)),
 ('a3', datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 13, 12, 35)),
 ('a2', datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 13, 12, 32)),
 ('b1', datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 13, 12, 30)),
 ('b2', datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 13, 12, 24))]
```

You can imagine the chained generators like a pipe, where the output pulls data from the chain when needed, so only the minimum necessary manipulations of data will take place. For more info and ideas about this use of generators, an interesting read is [this presentation](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/Generators.pdf) from [David Beazley](http://www.dabeaz.com).

Comment: @Oliort's warning should be heeded, I am indeed in that unfortunate situation where the lists I am dealing with have many more elements than the `k` I need (up to thousands of elements)

Comment: @Oliort You totally misunderstand what `heapq.merge` is. There is **no** loading of the lists, no creation of a new list. It uses iterators on the lists, and returns an iterator. Here, it just looks at the tuples of each list, and lazily yields the one with the largest time.

Comment: @HassanBaig You have large lists, that's exactly why this solution, using iterators on the lists all the way, is perfectly adapted to such a situation.

Comment: Thanks, everything is clear, I will accept the answer. Btw, one more thing. It would be great in case you know a way to do this in older python versions too - ones that do not support  the optional arguments of `key` and `reverse`. That way, we will get a truly version agnostic solution, which would be useful in its on way.

Comment: My bad, had not reviewed your latest edit before submitting an edit of my own. Strangely, SO did not notify me either. Taking a look now.